# Stored procedures in delphi

Tags: sql, delphi, stored-procedures

I'm trying to call a stored procedure from some delphi code

I have a function like

```
procedure TDatabaseConnection.GetHourlyFiltergramLabSamples(StartTime, EndTime : TDateTime; Samples : TList<THourlyFilterCount>);
var
    StoredProc : TADOStoredProc;
begin
    StoredProc := TADOStoredProc.Create(nil);
    try
        StoredProc.Connection := Connection;
        StoredProc.ProcedureName := 'GetHourlyFiltergramLabSamples';

        StoredProc.Parameters.Refresh;

        StoredProc.Parameters.ParamByName('@StartTime').Value := startTime;
        StoredProc.Parameters.ParamByName('@EndTime').Value   := EndTime;

        StoredProc.Open;

        while not StoredProc.Eof do
        begin
            //Do stuff with the results here ... 

            StoredProc.Next;
        end;

    finally
        FreeAndNil(StoredProc);
    end;
end;
```

When I hit the line StoredProc.Open;

I get an error

> 'CommandText does not return a result set.'

I have checked using SQL server management studio that the stored procedure does in fact return results.

[image: StoredProc]

I've found that this issues seems to be temperamental. Surely this isn't a bug in the database connector??

I'm out of ideas

Comment: I've been looking at this article ( http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesDelphi12& ) for how to use stored procedures

Comment: My Stored procedure had SET NOCOUNT ON; in it, i've just removed that line and the problem has gone away ... for now

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms189837.aspx

Comment: To circumvent your problem, you can use `TADOQuery`instead of `TADOStoredProc`.

Comment: I still want to use stored procedures. I've tried using TADOCommand and then set ADOCommand1.CommandType := cmdStoredProc;
But this gives me the same problem. Its looking like TADOStoredProc does not like SET NOCOUNT ON in the stored procedure.

Comment: You can use stored procedures in TADOQuery, use the same syntax as you would in managament studio,only parameter syntax is a bit different, ie: 'EXEC GetHourlyFiltergramLabSamples :StartTime :EndTime'

Comment: What version of Delphi and SQL Server is this? I don't see any issues with `SET NOCOUNT ON` in SPs that return sets on Delphi 6 + SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I'm actually using embarcadero XE6 and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (X64)

Comment: I should also add that this seems to have been a temperamental issue I've been having with using stored procedures in pascal. Since removing SET NOCOUNT ON I have not yet had a problem.

Comment: This is article is concerning http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.database.ado/201101/1101071772.html

Comment: I have witnessed this bug again, this time even with the SET NOCOUNT ON not present in the query

Comment: I've added into the query SET NOCOUNT OFF, the problem has not reappeared yet. I cant be sure that fixed the problem though

Comment: FYI, I've just observed this happening while using SET NOCOUNT OFF;

Comment: It it possible that the stored procedure is exiting prematurely, and really isn't returning a result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this one open for a number of months now.

The best solution I have is to switch to using FireDAC. I have not had the same issues when using FireDAC to execute stored procedures.

instead I use the `TFDStoredProc` type to run stored procedures